# MySQL update method in java not working correctly

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have written the following UPDATE method for my MySQL database.

```
public int update(User u) {

    int status = 0;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement stm = null;

    try {
        connection = ConnectionConfiguration.getConnection();
        stm = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE users SET f_name=? 
              l_name=? WHERE id=?");

        stm.setString(1, u.getName());
        stm.setString(2, u.getLname());
        stm.setInt(3, u.getId());

        status = stm.executeUpdate();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(stm != null) {
            try {
                stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } return status;

}
```

Then I update the data in a JSP class like below:

```
<% int id =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Userid")); 
   UserM um = new UserM(); 
   User u = new User();
   u = um.select(id);
%>
<form method="GET" action="EditServlet">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=u.getId()%>">
Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<%=u.getName()%>"><br>
Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" value="<%=u.getLname()%>"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

In the EditServlet I have written the following code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String rid=request.getParameter("id");  
    int id=Integer.parseInt(rid);  
    String fname =request.getParameter("fname");  
    String lname=request.getParameter("lname");  


    User u =new User();  
    u.setName(fname);  
    u.setLname(lname); 
    u.setId(id);
    UserM um = new UserM(); 
    int up_status = um.update(u);  

    if(up_status > 0) {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/GetUserInfo").forward(request, response); 
    } else {  
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Could not change info");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/GetUserInfo").forward(request, response);  
    }

}
```

After I run the code and update the data it shows the error message everytime. Is there anything wrong with the implementation of my code?

Comment: *it shows the error message everytime* - and what would that error be?  Also in `update` what is `res` ?

Comment: the error message is the one I have specified with  request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Could not change info"); That's all it does. It does not update any data

Comment: No, it doesnt show any exceptions

Comment: *Unrelated:* Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to eliminate all that funky (and flaky) `close()` logic.

Comment: Also why are you doing the `select` part in JSP?, Are you sure that a record is retrieved? Why are you doing a `Get` when posting a form?  Time to do some debugging

Comment: I did a select in JSP bc I need to show the data in the form and yes the record is retrieved. Also when posting the error message I did add the get methods for the user and it displays the new values that I enter but it just doesn't update them in the DB

Comment: I solved it. There was just a mistake in my SQL update

Comment: Can you please add what you did to your question, so that this question may be of use to other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In this code

```
User u =new User();  
u.setName(fname);  
u.setLname(lname);
```

you are not setting the value of the `User::id`, so when you go to use it in `update(User u)` the value will be zero.

change to

```
User u =new User();  
u.setName(fname);  
u.setLname(lname);
u.setId (id);
```

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I actually do have it in my code. I must have forgotten to write it in here.

Comment: Well in that case, it would appear that you do not have a User in your DB with that `id`

Comment: well I did check my DB and there is a user with the given id so I do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my SQL statement. I had forgotten a comma after f_name. It should have been:
"UPDATE users SET f_name=?, l_name=? WHERE id=?"

Comment: Version 1 of your question had this `,` - how can we successfully answer?

Comment: it was because when I wrote it here i put it and in my original code I had forgotten it